# How are the page-break properties in CSS supposed to work?

Tags: css, printing

Modern browsers are [supposed to support the CSS page-break properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117772/which-browsers-support-page-break-manipulation-using-css-and-the-page-break-insid/117834#117834) to some degree. However I haven't been able to get any browser to print any differently when I use `avoid`, `widows`, or `orphans`. Am I doing it wrong, or is the browser support just not as solid as advertised?

```
      h2 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
      }                         

      p {
        page-break-inside: avoid;   
        orphans: 2;
        widows: 2;
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browser support for printing sucks.  Not just a little bit, but completely totally and without compare.  About once every other year (for the past 10), I've played around with this and I always come back to the same conclusion: don't depend on the browser to be able to handle good printing.

If it absolutely must be positioned correctly, create a pdf file on the fly and let the user print that.

Comment: We're now in the 3rd decade of terrible print support in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do a page break I know that this is the way it works at least in Firefox and IE. Last time I checked this worked in IE7.

```
Page 1

<br style="page-break-after:always" />

Page 2
```

It *should* print the pages on separate pieces of paper, totally depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will go against everything everyone says about html development, but use **tables**.  Put content that needs to stay together into a table, and then the page will not be split in the middle of the table.  If the table is longer than one page, then it will be split somewhere in the middle of the table, but using tables is a good way to keep content together when printing.

Comment: Considering that you could use the table layout model in CSS, it wouldn't even have to affect semantics of the markup.

Comment: Actually having a problem currently where IE doesn't split the table over multiple pages and instead loses the second half of the table....