# How to break page and repeat header after 20 records while printing data grid data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, printing, header, repeat

I want to print a web page using a datagrid to show some data. It prints data, but does not repeat the header in next page. I would like the header repeated in each page. How can I do it with a datagrid? I can do it using style break in the table head, but can't in datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

[You can create a print style sheet.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#propdef-page-break-before)  However, [support for it is still sparse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117772/which-browsers-support-page-break-manipulation-using-css-and-the-page-break-insid)
 
 
For predicatble paging and formatting, I would output to either PDF or a reporting tool such as Crystal Reports.