# Rails generate PDF from html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf, pdfkit

I'm facing some problems to generate PDF from html with Rails. I tried to use [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) and [Wicked_PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gems, with both I had a problem with page break, **they break inside a `<tr>`**.

Let me show you what I'm doing with `Wicked_PDF`:

In my controller:

```
render pdf: "report", 
       :template => "reports/index.html.erb",
       :layout => "pdf",
       :orientation => 'Landscape',
       footer: {
         right: "Page [page] of [topage]",
         font_size: 9
       }
```

layouts/pdf.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
      .table {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
          border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
          padding: 2px;
          text-align: left;
          vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .table > thead th {
          background: #f7f7f7;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

reports/index.html.erb:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>Example of a text that breaks the tr</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% 3.times do %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= "string " * 500 %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also tried to use this css property:

```
tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

**Note**: I think it would not be relevant to show what I did with `PDFKit`, since the html and css doesn't change, only the way it is rendered and the problem is exactly the same.

**What I've missed?**

Solutions with other gems are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

For PDFkit you can also use this property

```css
.table{
  tr{
    page-break-before: always !important;
  }
}
```

You can also try a bunch of workarounds mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: @RuiSchnaiderJúnior Which version of wkhtmltopdf library are you using? Page breaks are a known issue for older versions.

Comment: the version is wkhtmltopdf-0.12.2.1-1.fc20.x86_64.