# knp snappy bundle table rows

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I use KnpSnappyBundle for generating pdf from html pages in Symfony 2. I have problem with pages that have tables. Row which is on edge of page is sometimes printed over another row. How to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Link to picture that shows problem: http://postimg.org/image/6o8fhup51/

Comment: Do not use <thead>, <th>, <tbody> tags or try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf - it worked for me.