# How to group <TR> in a table for page-break?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I have a table will a large number of datarecords and print it with WKHTMLTOPDF.
In the old version of my script (PHP) there was 1 `<tr>` per datarecord like this:

`<tr><td>$row->date $row->username $row->subject 
 <br> $row->multi_line_text </td></tr>`

The "line-break"-rules from WKHTMLTOPDF works fine (so when the end of the current cell (`<tr><td>`) is not on the current page, the cell will begin on the next page.

Now, every datarecord has 2 rows, because the first has now 3 columns:

`<tr><td>$row->date</td><td>$row->username</td><td>$row->subject</td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan=3> $row->multi_line_text </td></tr>`

...and now it can happend, that the first line is on page one and the second on page two.

How can I "group" the both `<tr>` together?
A own `<table>` for every datarecord is no solution, because the 3 columns has to be everytime the same width.

Thank you
Olli

Comment: A `<tbody>` for every datarecord.

Comment: @MrLister yes, thank you! This works in Firefox, but WKhtmlToPDF ignore page-breaks declaration - https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1551  :-(

Comment: Sorry about that; not familiar with WKhtmlToPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Hava e look at [How to avoid page break inside table row for wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf/30364753#30364753) and
[WKHTMLTOPDF - Allow page break in table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927351/wkhtmltopdf-allow-page-break-in-table-row)

And you write:

A own  for every datarecord is no solution, because the 3 columns has to be everytime the same width.

You might want control the width with CSS.

Or go for a `div` based solution althogether.