# wkhtmltopdf page break gets worse with more pages

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I'm converting [this html](https://new.nameprintgraphics.com/html.html) into a pdf using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4 64-bit on Windows. I need to have a page break after every table as the next table will appear on the next page. This will be used for label printing so accuracy is key.

[This is the resulting PDF](https://new.nameprintgraphics.com/pdf.pdf)

The first two pages are perfect but then it starts going south for inexplicable reasons.

I've tried the options presented in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf) and subsequent hyperlinked threads but nothing helped, I've yet to see an affect with `page-break-inside: avoid !important;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this css style for page break and it work fine.

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Use this div in your html view, in your case after table.
and add style in your css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .page-break { display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always; }
</style>
```