# where to add page-break related css in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

*I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2 on Windows.*

I know there are a lot of questions and answers around this topic, but I still can't find an answer to my problem; I don't know where to put the according CSS - or the CSS doesn't work for some (other) reason:

for example i tried to put the page-break related CSS directly into my html file which i want to render. i tried to force page-breaks with `<span class="break_here"></span>` in my `<body>`:

```
<!-- ... -->
<head>
    <style>
        span.break_here {
            page-break-after: always !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

this didn't do anything.

then i also tried to put it into `@media print{}` or `@media screen{}` which did not change anything either:

```
<style>
    @media screen{
        span.break_here {
            page-break-after: always !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

thanks for any help!

**edit:** there is even another possibility by adding the `--user-style-sheet` option for using an external stylesheet.

Comment: Page breaking makes sense only when talking about printing a html page, because the content gets separated into actual pages then. When viewing a rendered html in a browser, page breaking makes no sense since it is shown as a continuous screen. So, what is it exactly that you want? To make these elements show only one at a time in each page when printing?

Answer (score 0):

Adding pagebreaks via a standalone element in wkhtmltopdf has caused me problems as well.

I've found that applying the pagebreaks to an element which wraps the contents to be much more reliable.

This doesn't work so well:

```
<div>some content</div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
```

Whereas this does the trick:

```
<div class="pagebreak">some content</div>
```

To make this work, I did not use `.pagebreak{page-break-after: always!important;}`

But, instead used: `.pagebreak{page-break-inside: avoid!important;}`

It's also good to note that pagebreaks on print should be as high-up in the dom-tree as possible. Applying pagebreak rules to elements that are deeply nested can cause headaches (or at least has for me in the past)

Hope this helps!