# Wicked_pdf avoid page-break-inside not working

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, page-break, page-break-inside

This is the result when i use Wicked_pdf to convert my `html.erb` page to `pdf`.

[image]

**Problem**: Seem `table` 's `tr` has been splitted into two pages.

**What i tried without success**:

1. Use `page-break-inside` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874452/2594699)

> table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
>       page-break-inside: avoid !important; }

2. putting text within a div, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table/17982110#17982110)
3. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978778/2594699)

> Another option: place each tr in its own tbody and then apply the
>   peage break css rules to the tbody. Tables support multiple tbodys.
>   A bit of extra markup, but works decently for me.

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.2.6, Wicked_pdf latest version, bootstrap.

Relate [issue on github](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2141)

**Question**: How can i make `table` 's `tr` not split into two pages.

Comment: Your first page isn't filling up is it? I see no gap at the bottom of the first page which is why I ask. If it fills up, nothing will prevent the page break except defining a larger page when you run wkhtml2pdf. If you been provide a more complete screenshot a well as the exact HTML and CSS that you're using, you'll make more and better answers possible.

Comment: I created a pull request that fixes this issue in May last year. The project maintainer hasn't merged it yet. Grab my fork of the Qt project and compile it. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/qt/pull/29

Comment: The pull request has now been merged into the project. See if that solves your problem. We've had it in production since June last year without a repeat of the issue.

Comment: @RickMeasham Thank you. But how can i install this wkhtmltopdf package on my MAC or Centos server ?

Comment: @RickMeasham `without a repeat of the issue`, isn't just misleading but straight up false. Im on 0.12.4 and am still experiencing this problem

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley .. please re-read: "See if that solves your problem" doesn't promise it does. "We've had it .. without a repeat" is my experience. Again, no promises.

Comment: @RickMeasham sorry I thought you we're providing the perspective of a maintainer of the project

Answer (score 5):

well, to solve this you have to user `page-break-inside: avoid !important;` with the repeated div the results in this overflow.

**like if you have:**

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

which results in overflow that will make things overlap with the header within the page breaks..

so >> use: `page-break-inside: avoid !important;` with this class `article`.

```css
table.report-container div.article {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

---> [here is a full answer to print a page properly using html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371081/4846859)