# html-pdf. Render table works bad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, html-table, html-pdf

I'm using **[html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)** nodejs library to render html table to PDF. 
It seems all works good. But tables rows at the end of the page looks like broken.Here the results. [image]

I've already used page-break-inside rule. And I've also put DIV inside the table's cells. That all does not help me.

I'm using **meteor**+**react** bundle.

**Configuration**

```
const config= {
    "format": "A4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "border": {
        "top": "0.2in",
        "right": "0.2in",
        "bottom": "0.2in",
        "left": "0.2in"
    },
    "timeout": "120000",
    "type": "pdf",
}
```

**Server Side code:**

```
pdf.create(html, config).toFile(_storage_path, Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, res) => { .... }));
```

**Client Side**

```
    const html = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.PDF).outerHTML; 
    Meteor.call('vote.toPDF', html , function(res, err) {...});
```

Is there any way to avoid row breaking ? Did I miss anything ?

**(UPDATE) Here similar articles. There are a lot of other possible solutions:**

- [Avoid Page Break inside table row for wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf/13525758#13525758)
- [avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

Comment: Have you tried the `page-break-after:always;` CSS rule?

Comment: @Throlle, Yes, I've used this rule for **td** and **tr** tags. It not helping.

Comment: That's frustrating. Have you tried using `page-break-after:always;` on just your `tr` tags, and removing `page-break-inside` and`page-break-after` from your `table`?

Comment: @Tholle, I've tried different combinations. And nothing helped me.  =(
I forgot to mention that I've also used **borderSpacing: 0** rule for table.
And all other borders I've specified via **border: 1px solid black** rule(for table, tr,td)

Comment: Gotcha. Have you [tried this](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/226)?

Comment: @Throlle, Yeap. I tried it. I had find a lot of articles concerning this issue and they did not help me. 
Perhaps it happen due to meteor or react. However I'm passing the right data I suppose. 
Maybe I should have a rest for a while. Because I've spent a lot of time today in an attempt to solve this issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Tholle. Hello again. I've added **display: table** for each tr and defined **fixed** width for each **TD** and **TH**. So this has fixed my issue in spite of it's a dirty fix. For now, I think, I will use this solution. However, I will also try to find the best one. And if I find, I will publish the results here.
Thanks for your help =)