# Rotativa - Wkhtmltopdf has stopped working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I get the following exception (no actual message, just a stack trace) when trying to generate some PDF with Rotativa, in an ASP.NET MVC application.

> System.Exception    at Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String
>   wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)    at
>   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String
>   switches, String html)    at
>   Rotativa.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context)    at
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context)    at
>   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The issue is not related to missing C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2013(MSVCP120.dll), as they are installed on the machine. 
Actually, some PDF can be generated through the application, which makes me think there is something in the view that causes Wkhtmltopdf to stop working sometimes...

Any idea as to what causes this exception or how I could debug it?

(The Rotativa version is 1.6.4 I am using MVC5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a number of trials and errors. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf) also pointed me in the right direction. It is apparently an issue with wkhtmltopdf page breaking algorithm, and large table or HTML blocks. So, to solve my problem I changed my HTML into smaller chunks and it now works.