# HTML to PDF content spill over to next page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, htmldoc

I am using HTMLdoc to generate PDF out of html but I am facing issue while generating PDF.when the page split happens in the PDF, some of the content will get distributed across the page and we don't have control over that.

lets say you have table with 10 to 15 rows then first 10 rows will be on first page and remaining 5 rows on second page,worst part is that, If I have border for the table and some time even the content from same row will get spill over to next page and looks bad.

I agree the fact that we can't put everything into one page but I am looking for a solution where this spillover happens more gracefully like starts with table headers if possible if it spill over to next page or at-least content of same row remains in one page.

I am using Rails and [HTMLdoc](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) library to generate PDF.

[image]

Comment: If you are using table use Thead and Tbody and modern PDF render using set it nice.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered before, hope this helps:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

```
<table class="print-friendly">
 <!-- The rest of your table here -->
</table>

<style>
    table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: HTMLdoc has no effect on those CSS class,do you have any work around ?