# Print datatable - new page

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces, printing

I'm trying to print my datatable using `javascript` and `css` like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{portal.btnPrint}" type="submit" onclick="javascript: window.print();"/>

<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="item" value="#{myPrins.model}" ...
...
</p:dataTable>

@media print
{
  table { font-size: 80%; }
  #menu, #header, #form, #form_error { display: none; } 
  @page { size: A4 landscape !important; }
  ....
  ....
}
```

And, if I understand it weel, it's DOM based printing, so it just prints, what is set to be printed and visible on the screen.

Problem is, that I can't handle end of pages:
[image]

What I've tried and refused:

- styling `row heigth` or `font size` (problem happens again on the next pages)
- print the table per pages (1st page - print, 2nd page - print atc.). User-enemy for big datatable
- print header on each page using `@media print { thead {display: table-header-group;} }` - it works in Firefox only
- export to XLS (I can't from another reason)
- `page-break-inside: avoid;` doesn't work in chrome

How to print whole the datatable at once and automatically split the pages correct?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table  And what is MFF? (no results in google related to webdevelopment)

Comment: I guess MFF stands for Mozilla FireFox. Your best bet is to play with CSS or use a proper library dedicated to printing web pages such as  wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Ahhhh... right... MFF... But if these only work in MFF, and not webkit based browsers, will wkhtmltopdf work? I personally use flyingsaucer and it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Emergency solution**:

- Mozilla Firefox
- **css:** `@media print { tr { page-break-inside: avoid !important; } }`

**New issues & advantages**:

- Header is automatically on each page
- Border of table is shifted a bit to the left and top (from 2nd page)
- => I had to make top and left border of table a bit thicker enough to be visible on next pages:

  **css:** `@media print { table { border-top:  3px solid #ACBECE; .. } }`