# Repeating row headings in print preview for table / thead doesn't work correctly

Tags: html

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/10/12/repeating-html-table-headers-on-each-printed-page/

So I have a table with x number of rows and it has a `thead` and `tbody` section.

When I print preview it repeats the headings correctly. But for some reason it introduces a spurious row at the top of the next page:

Bottom of page 1:

[image: Page 1]

Top of page 2:

[image: Page 2]

When I look closely it has actually split that last row. Some of it is on one page and the tick is on the other. How do I prevent this?

My web content is being displayed in a `CHtmlView` control so needs to be **IE7** compatible.

This improves it:

[avoid page break inside row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

But I still get am empty row at the bottom on page 2 now. But overall it is an improvement.

## Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xs8074th/

Comment: where is your code

Comment: I didn't show it because it is full of real names. I can prepare something tomorrow.

Comment: take the names out and use fake names

Comment: @mlegg I added a fiddle.