# CSS to stop page break inside of table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, page-break-inside

I am trying to avoid having page breaks inside of rows for my HTML tables that may go past one page. I am using Internet Explorer Print Preview and also BCL EasyPDFSDK to convert to PDF to test this. I applied the following CSS styling in various combinations to the `<td>` elements but for each one I was getting an undesired result:

```
td {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

I believe the `page-break-inside: avoid !important` is working, but only on the `<td>` level. For example, I will see a `<tr>` that has one `<td>` on the end of the first page with all of the text intact, but the following `<td>` tags would be on the next page with all of their text intact.

I didn't think you were supposed to apply formatting to `<tr>` so I'm unsure how to go about fixing this.

Should I apply the CSS to the `<tr>` or is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? This would help

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I needed to collapse borders on the table element and reduce my padding to only 1px using

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: xx-small;
}
```

I also set the font-size to `xx-small` just in case that was causing an issue. The issue seemed to primarily be resolved when I collapsed borders, so it makes me wonder if the table was having issues splitting the rows because of that.

Cheers!

EDIT:

Since dealing with this issue, I have found out that the row splitting is handled much better in newer web browsers. I highly recommend updating IE to at least 11 if you are experiencing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I just added the below css to my @media print and it worked!!!

None of the solutions applied to td, th, tr worked

```css
table {
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked.  The question implies a table that cannot fit on a single page, so you do want some breaks within a table; you just want them at row boundaries.