# How to avoid page break in a dynamic list when exporting pdf with rotativa?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rotativa

How to set page break in dynamic content rotativa ?

I have a list of lists which loads data dynamically through a model binding

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div class="separator-bottom col-xs-12 avoid-page-break">
        <div>
            (generates the list)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And my `avoid-page-break` class is like this

```
 .avoid-page-break {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        margin: 4px 0 4px 0
  }
```

I followed, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table/17982110#17982110) answer. I've used the styling as mentioned in it. It solves the issue in 1st page, but still having the issue from 2nd page onwards.

Is there any workaround to solve this ? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is this not more of a CSS problem than C# or .NET? PS I'm afraid I don't know the answer lol

Comment: @DavidC799 This works in normal HTML (View) So this seems like more of a rotativa extension problem. Researched a bit about it. Many have faced this issue in different scenarios when they're using rotativa extension to export the pdf.

Comment: Ah apologies then, I've never heard of that extension before.

Answer (score -1):

this is a problem with how Rotativa renders the page.
Do like this:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid !important">
   <div style="break-inside: avoid-page !important;">
     sub-content 01
   </div>
   <div style="break-inside: avoid-page !important;">
     sub-content 02
   </div>
```

what will happen is that between sub-content 01 and 02 there will be a page break if necessary.

NOTE: If the sub-content 01 is large enough to break only one page, nothing will happen to it.