# How do you prevent splitting the results of a List Rows operation over several pages?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table containing pictures and names neatly packed into a single, printable A4 page. The pictures and names are fetched from a database using a List Rows call. However, the closest I've come looks right viewed in the browser, but each row is moved to a separate page when printing.

So far I've tried to simply import a fixed number of pictures/images as columns in a table, collected in one row. In the browser, it displays more or less like I want it to, but when I try to print it, each row becomes a separate page. The code for this looks like the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container { width: 100px; }

#image {width: 100%; }

#text { text-align: justify; }    
</style>


<table>
<tr>
<List Rows=12>
        
    <td> <div id="container">
    <img src="<Picture>" height="123px"/>
    <p id="text"> <Name> </p> </td>
    
</List>
</tr>

</table>
```

I thought I could get around this by importing the List Rows one after the other in the same query, but then each row is an identical copy of the row above, and not just a continuation. I.e., the approach below does *not* work, but just creates two identical rows after each other, before switching to a new page and doing the next two identical rows:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container { width: 100px; }

#image {width: 100%; }

#text { text-align: justify; }    
</style>


<table>
<tr>
<List Rows=12>
        
    <td> <div id="container">
    <img src="<Picture>" height="123px"/>
    <p id="text"> <Name> </p> </td>
    
</List>
</tr>
<tr>
<List Rows=12>
        
    <td> <div id="container">
    <img src="<Picture>" height="123px"/>
    <p id="text"> <Name> </p> </td>
    
</List>
</tr>

</table>
```

I've run out of ideas on how to get this working. The context I'm working in does not allow for separately uploaded CSS files, so all CSS options have to be included in the HTML-file itself.

Would it be possible to list them all after each other and have automatic line breaks when the paper width is reached? So far I haven't had any luck with this approach, but maybe someone on here has a good idea.

Creative workarounds (eg. changing print settings somehow) are also welcome.

(I'm not sure how to create a small test database to create a minimum working example, so I hope my descriptions suffice.)

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avoid page break inside row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

Comment: you can make css rules specifically for printing using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#print)

Comment: DBS - Thanks for the suggestion! I tried the top 3 solutions, but it either kept splitting it up, or just straight up gave an error message. I'm getting a little worried that the page break may be implemented elsewhere, as the HTML code I'm doing it used in a much bigger, separate system.
IT goldman - I'm not sure how to do the media queries inside the HTML doc. Is it possible, and if so, how? I can't upload a separate CSS file, unfortunately