# page-break-inside causes unknown spaces in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using    `page-break-inside : avoid ;`  and some java script to prevent tables from breaking over two pages, it's working correctly but it's adding random spacing between tables. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

I'm only having this issue in chrome, anyone know how I can get rid of these spaces?
[image]

```
table {

    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
    page-break-inside : avoid ;
    position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but have you tried surrounding the `table` with a `div` element and applying the `page-break-inside: avoid;` property to that instead? Not exactly a solution, but perhaps it would work for you.

Comment: @SombreErmine that was exactly it if you want to submit it as an answer ill approve it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be various possible reasons `page-break-inside` would work oddly in Google Chrome or Webkit browsers in general:

- [page-break-inside doesn't work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706504/page-break-inside-doesnt-work-in-chrome)
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097

The easiest solution would be to add the `page-break-inside: avoid;` to a surrounding `div` element instead.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="no-page-break">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.no-page-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```