# first page getting empty when use page break inside

Tags: html, css

I am using `page-break-inside: avoid;` to avoid the break inside the element.
But if the element content has more than one page it is creating new blank space and the element goes to next page in print/converting to pdf.

Can you help me to come out from this? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class='padding-top' style='page-break-inside: avoid;'>
   <div class='important' style='min-height:20px;'>
       <div class='imp-content'><span class='imp-header'
        style='text-transform:uppercase;float:left;'>Important<sup>
         {{data}} 
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Explain more in details. Also add some code.

Comment: can you provide some code or a snippet then only we will be able to understand the exact issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [page-break-inside doesn't work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706504/page-break-inside-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

Comment: @AdeshKumar Thanks for reply but that is not exact solution

Comment: @user1850484  Please check the code snippet. Thanks

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Comment: Google Chrome 78.0.3904.70

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans) CSS worked for me:

```
@media print {
  body {
    orphans: 0;
  }
}
```